# Is it possible to make virtual tours using images in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, virtual, react-360

I am trying to build a feature in my app that takes couple of images of a place and transfer them into a virtual tour but I couldn't figure out how to do it using react native expo, I saw some examples they were using react-360 but I'm not sure if I can use it inside my react native expo or not, or if there are other components can make that for me?
Please if you have any idea about that let me know.